# Dependent observable property in Matlab. Does it work?

Tags: oop, events, matlab, properties, event-handling

In Matlab class it seems to be syntactically correct to declare *property* that is *Dependent* (computed not stored) and  *Observable* in the same time. Consider code

```
properties (Access = private)
    instanceOfAnotherClass
end
properties (SetAccess = private, Dependent, SetObservable)
    propertyTwo
end
methods
    function val = get.propertyTwo(this)
        val = this.instanceOfAnotherClass.propertyOne;   
    end
end
```

Does this work as expected? That is, if the property `propertyOne` of an object stored in `instanceOfAnotherClass` is changed is there property change event triggered by `propertyTwo`? Note that `propertyOne` is not *Observable*.

**Edit:**
It does not work (as I expected). 'PostSet' event is not triggered. So how do I deal with this kind of situation? Is there a better solution then to create `propertyTwo` as a non *Dependent* and set it to the same value as 'propertyOne' every time 'propertyOne' changes?

**Edit2:**
In reaction to [Amro's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro) [edit of his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653138/311865) I will explain situation more complex.
Consider this 2 classes:

```
 classdef AClass < handle
     properties
         a
     end
 end
 classdef BClass < handle
     properties (Access = private)
         aClassInst
     end
     properties (Dependent, SetObservable, SetAccess = private)
         b
     end
     methods
         function this = BClass(aClass)
             this.aClassInst = aClass;
         end
         function val = get.b(this)
             val = this.aClassInst.a;
         end
     end
 end
```

The class that uses all this code should not get access to `AClass`. It interacts only with instance of `BClass` and wants to listen to changes of property `b`. however if I make property `a` of `AClass` observable that would not solve my problem, would it? The 'PostSet' events are not going to propagate to property `b`, are they?

Comment: Why didn't you test it on a minimal test example?

Comment: @mutzmatron Good point :) I could test it myself. But in the fact I expected it not to work and wanted some ideas on how to make it work... Or good practises on this kind of problem. I should edit my question and ask right questions this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be syntactically correct, but the listener callback will never execute. Example:

```
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties (Access = public)
        a
    end
    properties (SetAccess = private, Dependent, SetObservable)
        b
    end
    methods
        function val = get.b(this)
            val = this.a;
        end
    end
end
```

Now try:

```
c = MyClass();
lh = addlistener(c, 'b', 'PostSet',@(o,e)disp(e.EventName));
c.a = 1;
disp(c.b)
```

As you can see the 'PostSet' callback is never executed.

---

### EDIT

The way I see it, `SetObservable` should really be set on `a` not `b`. Its because `b` is read-only and can only change if `a` changes. Now the `PostSet` event would notify us that both properties have changed.

Use the same example I used above, simply move `SetObservable` from `b` to `a`. Of course now you listen to the event as:

```
lh = addlistener(c, 'a', 'PostSet',@(o,e)disp(e.EventName));
```

---

### EDIT#2

Sorry I didn't pay attention to the fact that you have composition (BClass has an instance of AClass as private property).

Consider this possible solution:

#### AClass.m

```
classdef AClass < handle
    properties (SetObservable)
        a                        %# observable property
    end
end
```

#### BClass.m

```
classdef BClass < handle
    properties (Access = private)
        aClassInst               %# instance of AClass
        lh                       %# event listener on aClassInst.a
    end
    properties (Dependent, SetAccess = private)
        b                        %# dependent property, read-only
    end
    events (ListenAccess = public, NotifyAccess = private)
        bPostSet                 %# custom event raised on b PostSet
    end
    methods
        function this = BClass(aClass)
            %# store AClass instance handle
            this.aClassInst = aClass;
            %# listen on PostSet event for property a of AClass instance
            this.lh = addlistener(this.aClassInst, 'a',  ...
                'PostSet', @this.aPostSet_EventHandler);
        end
        function val = get.b(this)
            val = this.aClassInst.a;
        end
    end
    methods (Access = private)
        function aPostSet_EventHandler(this, src, evt)
            %# raise bPostSet event, notifying all registered listeners
            notify(this, 'bPostSet')
        end
    end
end
```

Basically we set property `a` of AClass as observable.

Next inside the constructor of BClass, we register a listener for the AClass instance passed to listen on property `a` changes. In the callback we notify listeners of this object that `b` has changed as well

Since we can't really raise a `PostSet` manually, I created a custom event `bPostSet` which we raise in the previous callback function. You can always customize the event data passed, refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brb6gnc.html#brb6i_k) to see how.

Here is a test case:

```
%# create the objects
a = AClass();
b = BClass(a);

%# change property a. We will not recieve any notification
disp('a.a = 1')
a.a = 1;

%# now lets listen for the 'bChanged' event on b
lh = addlistener(b, 'bPostSet',@(o,e) disp('-- changed'));

%# try to change the property a again. We shall see notification
disp('a.a = 2')
a.a = 2;

%# remove event handler
delete(lh)

%# no more notifications
disp('a.a = 3')
a.a = 3;
```

The output was:

```
a.a = 1
a.a = 2
-- changed
a.a = 3
```

Notice how we only interact with the BClass instance when we register our listener. Of course since all classes derive from `handle` class, the instance `a` and the private property `aClassInst` both refer to the same object. So any changes to `a.a` are immediately reflected on `b.aClassInst.a`, this causes the internal `aPostSet_EventHandler` to execute, which in turn notify all registered listeners to our custom event.

Comment: That is what I expected... But I don't like it. Is there some way to make it work? What if the a was observable? Would 'PostSet' execute? I don't have Matlab on this computer to try it. And if not would what shell I do in order to make it work?

Comment: @drasto: see my edit. I propose you make the property `a` as `SetObservable` not `b`

Comment: Well, I could do that but property `a` is not accessible by the client class because it is property of different class that. So client class cannot listen directly to changes of `a`. Please see my edit for details.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly as clear as I wanted but I guess close enough. I'll wait if there are more responses and if not I'll accept your answer. Thank you again.