# MATLAB event attributes

Tags: matlab, events

I have two questions about event attributes in MATLAB.

i) With a regular event, it's possible to set the `ListenAccess` attribute of the event to restrict access to where you can create listeners for that event. Is it possible to do something similar for property events (in particular, a property's `PostSet` event)?

ii) Say I have a class `a` with an event `myEvent` defined, which has default attributes. If I have a subclass `b` of `a`, is it possible to redefine some of the attributes of the `myEvent` event in `b`? In particular, can I make the `myEvent` event `Hidden` in `b` but not `a`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For (i), does [Amro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11653138/2778484) help? He seems to be creating a property event and setting its `ListenAccess` property.

Comment: @chappjc Unfortunately I don't think it does. In that answer, @Amro has one property event firing another regular event, and is setting the `ListenAccess` of the second event. But the original property event still has `SetObservable` set to true, so can also be listened to directly by anything.